# Grouped Product is shown in Configurable product view!

Tags: grouped-products, magento1.7.0.2

I am trying to set up grouped products in my store. I created a grouped product with using magento admin panel and associated it with 2 simple products. Product is created but when I try to access grouped product's page I see the normal product page.

I checked the **local.xml** and there is nothing related to grouped products template. I checked the **catalog.xml** and I found that the grouped product template is set to

```
template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml"
```

Which is correct. But I still see the normal product template when ever I call the page

```
/gr1.html
```

I am in need of some help on this issue.

I use Magento CE 1.7.0.2

Cheers

Comment: No one had this issue before? I am still looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem via creating an IF statement in product view. Checked for the type of the product and then load the proper design for it. This fixed the issue.